# How to hide ongoing Notification while running foreground service in Android?

Tags: android-service

I tried to start service as unkillable by using **startForeground()**. But, its always running ongoing notification in the notification bar. I want to hide this ongoing notification. So, is it possible to hide ongoing notification while running foreground service in Android? or else any other cases to prevent service killable in Android

Thanking you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kind of cheating, but don't call startForeground() and instead call startService() on yourself.

```
startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

Comment: Thanking you **Philip Pearl** for your quick response. But in startService() will kill by OS. But, i need my service as not killable how can i ? is it possible without using startForeground() ?

Comment: from onCreate() call startService() to increase your reference count.  From onStartCommand() return START_STICKY.  Don't call stopSelf().  You should find your service is never killed

Comment: In Android 8.0+ (API 26+) the system will kill the service after a few minutes if you do not use startForegroundService().